# img(src=require(...)) generates ugly html

Tags: webpack, pug, pug-loader

I have written pug-file with the next content:

```
img(src=require("../../assets/icons/icon.png"))
```

And try to build it to html by Webpack by using the next webpack config:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/i,
        use: {
          loader: 'pug-loader', 
          options: {
            pretty: true
          },
        },
      },

....

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|jpeg|gif)$/,
        exclude: [
         /Montserrat-Bold.svg$/,
         /Montserrat-Regular.svg$/,
         /Quicksand-Regular.svg$/,
         ],
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "assets/icons/",
              publicPath: '../assets/icons/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
.....
```

As a result it builds into

```
<img src="{&quot;default&quot;:&quot;../assets/icons/icon.png&quot;}">
```

And image does not load when I open html-page with this content.

What should I do to build `img(src=require("../../assets/icons/icon.png"))` into `<img src="../assets/icons/icon.png">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It need to add `esModule: false` to file-loader options:

```
  use: [
      {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]",
          outputPath: "assets/icons/",
          publicPath: '../assets/icons/',
          esModule: false,
        }
      }
    ]
```

I found this answer here: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091138/webpack-2-pug-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-require